# When I log in, on a tty instance it immediately asks for my sudo password

Tags: bash, zsh, login, tty

So I am attempting to log in on a tty, and it looks something like this :

```
Arch Linux (tty1)
hostname login: _
```

```
Password: _
```

```
Last Login at (Date) on (tty1)
[sudo] password for user: _
```

And I think because of this I am unable to use a DM to login

This just started and I have no idea why.

at first I thought it was a problem with my .zshrc but I deleted its contents and the error persisted.

Does anyone have any clues to what might be causing this? or where I could look to find more info?

Thanks.

Comment: Also check your PAM configs.

Answer (score 1):

Something in one of your shell initialization files is calling `sudo`. Remove it.

First, check what your login shell is:

```
getent passwd $USER
```

Your login shell is the part after the last `:` sign. Check its login-time initialization files:

- For sh: `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile`
- For bash: `~/.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile`
- For zsh: `~/.zprofile`, `.zlogin`, `/etc/zsh/zprofile`, `/etc/zsh/zlogin`

Search for `sudo` in the file that your login shell uses. If you can't find it, add `set -x` at the top of these files, which will display each command immediately before it's executed. Whatever you see before the sudo prompt is the culprit.